# Find all possible combinaisons from a vector list

Tags: python, combinations

I try to find all combinaison from a vector list and all my combinaison should be with more than 2 elements. I managed to find all combinaison for exactly 2 elements but not all possible combinaisons (2-3...)

```
import itertools

Vect = ['element1','element2','element3','element4']

def Group(Data,n):
    GroupData = list(itertools.combinations(Data,n))
    return GroupData

Test = Group(Vect,2)
```

The result is

```
[('element1', 'element2'),
 ('element1', 'element3'),
 ('element1', 'element4'),
 ('element2', 'element3'),
 ('element2', 'element4'),
 ('element3', 'element4')]
```

Comment: `[list(combinations(Vect,n)) for n in list(range(2,len(Vect)+1))]`?

Comment: Can you add your desired output?